# Numbness - Is my bike fit ok?

Tags: road-bike, bike-fit

I have been enjoying road cycling for a couple of seasons now, but I have yet to find a good solution for the perineum numbness I am experiencing. By shifting around and standing up I can somewhat prevent it from happening, but I would love to find a good solution for it long term. Here's a couple of pictures - is there something way off with my fit? Is my bike not the right size? I'm 187 cm (6' 1") and my bike is a size 57.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I can imagine the seat might have something to do with it. Could you perhaps [edit] in what kind of seat/padding you have?

Comment: You've left out a lot of information that might get you a better answer.  How many different saddles have you tried?  How long can your ride before you start getting numb?  How often do you ride?  Have you tried shorts with more (or less) padding?

Comment: I switched to a different saddle with a cutout this winter while riding on a trainer. This is my second saddle so far. I have tried three different shorts + padding, and although the experience is different, it does not seem to affect my numbness too much. Its hard to tell exactly how long I can ride for before experiencing numbness, but Id guess its around the 7km mark it starts happening.

Comment: Switch to recumbent riding and it will no problem anymore (but that is for the extreme cases where a normal saddle switch is not enough.)

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/9384/23605

Comment: Did you buy this bike from a LBS and/or someone who fit you for it? It's hard to tell, but you seem to be sitting more upright than I'm used to seeing, almost as if your hands are too close to your knees... like too short top tube or something? Not an answer because I'm not sure and I don't have sources and pictures and stuff.

Comment: No, I bought it as is - so it was never fit to me or anything. When looking at the pictures I too feel like something is slightly off/small, but I am perfectly comfortable riding it (except for the numbness) so I'm not sure what to think.

Answer (score 1):

I would try changing saddle to mitigate or remove the problem.

Out of personal experience, and I have rode also on bikes which were too small for my body because it was that or nothing, the saddle is the most important aspect for numbness.

So much that I have kept my saddle over the last 3 bikes I have used in the last 8 years for commuting.

Comment: I switched to a different saddle with a cutout this winter while riding on a trainer. This is my second saddle so far. I might try another one, but I wanted to see if anyone saw anything obviously off about my fit first :)